# How to find the indexOf element in ArrayList in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to find the index of an element from an arraylist using powershell script,however getting the below given error

> Method invocation failed because [System.String[]] doesn't contain a
>   method named 'IndexOf'.

Code Used:

```
[String[]]$eventList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$eventList.GetType().FullName 
$index = $eventList.IndexOf('cvv');
```

Comment: What is 'cvv' in this context?

Comment: Sadly, I don't think powershell arrays support `IndexOf`.

Comment: 'cvv' is an string that i m trying to find in $eventList which is null the thing is i want the location of 'cvv' in  $eventList  null it should return '-1' but it is returning error

Answer (score 1):

You are casting the ArrayList to an array, just remove the cast:

```
$eventList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
```

Also, you might want to consider using a List<string> instead of an ArrayList:

```
$eventList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
```

Comment: `List<string>` for the win! It'll also allow you to find indices based on predicates rather than string literals: `$evenList.FindIndex({param($s) $s -match 'cv[u-z]'})`

Comment: $s represents the item in the list